# Notepad++ replace first comma in a line

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to use Notepad++ to replace a character IF it comes after a number.

For example, I have this:

```
1,String,anotherString
2,String,anotherString
3,String,anotherString
4,String,anotherString
5,String,anotherString
```

So I want to replace all the commas but only the ones that come after an integer (*not* taking the other comma) by an empty space.

The result would be this:

```
1 String,anotherString
2 String,anotherString
3 String,anotherString
4 String,anotherString
5 String,anotherString
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the part you need. You can check something like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DD6uK6/1) to get a better understanding of it. The following screenshot contains a possible regular expression to match what you need. It does expect the line to start with a number and the replace contains the match + a space.

It's important to select that you want to do a regular expression based search on the lower left of the dialog.

With your example you could also just search for `,String,` and replace it by `String,` and get the same effect but I'm assuming it's just a placeholder.

[image: Notepad++ search and replace dialog]

Comment: Thank you so much sir! It worked!